# How to stop custom function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, exit

look at this code

```js
const code = "..." // can be anything, it is unknown 
const func = new Function(code)

// run `func` and ignore possible errors in code
function run() {
  try { func() } finally {}
}

// stop `func` execution
function stop() {
  ???
}

$runButton.onclick = run
$stopButton.onclick = stop
```

Is there any way to stop function execution

I just need to rerun function multiple times, kind of playground

But if code has timers, or infinite loops it freezes behaves badly

I don't want to reload playground site every time

Any ideas?

[Same Situation in TS Playground, they don't care (press run multiple times)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/M4FwhgTiAUCUBQ8zAJ4DsDGACAZgV0xAEsB7NLUSGWLAb3i1xIi2gBsBTELIgXgAYA3DwA8ARn6ThRANQya9RozAB3MEW7BOHAA7QATJIRKsGMsBKcAdGxIBzaEWNYAvvDfx8hUuS0dd0AC2wABcWGh4gQBGHBAKDFgQXHgQ5GgcKlgAChAkgUTAHNAsvAB8FFwAKkSBHCR4MBAANFjBsAguQA)

Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536055/stopping-a-javascript-function-when-a-certain-condition-is-met), but that does not make sense
If that function's body is unpredictable

Also another way, which seems to be the most inefficient

Put checks in every line of function's body, and if flag is false break main label which is declared at the top of function's body for 'return' effect

```
let isRunning = true

code.split('/n').map(line => ';' + `if (!isRunning) break functionLabel` + ';' + line)

const functionBody = `functionLabel: { ${code} }`

const func = new Function(functionBody)
```

Comment: you can't stop it unless its running in its own context. javascript is single threaded

Comment: @DanielA.White maybe run with web workers a good idea? Does something that kind makes sense?

Comment: how if you put a state like `if(state) func()` and `$stopButton.onclick` make `state = false`

Comment: it depends.....

Comment: i didnt see any looping on your code

Comment: if you using `let interval = setInteval()` make `$stopButton.click` do `clearInterval(interval)`

Comment: @IrvanHilmi It's running arbitrary code that was received dynamically, it may contain a loop.

Comment: alright that make sense

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843201/how-to-clearinterval-with-unknown-id how about clear all interval

Comment: for looping with `for` `while` etc, like Daniel mention, its kinda imposible

Comment: @IrvanHilmi Sure, I can clear all intervals, but what if is there's infinite loops and promises

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) and pass code as message,
theoretically, it should run it in the background not affecting the main thread. Then [terminate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#terminating_a_worker) worker if you need to stop execution

For multiple 'reruns' reinit worker

worker.js

```js
self.addEventListener('message', event => {
  const { code  } = event.data
  const func = new Function(code)
  try {
    func()
    self.postMessage('code ran successfully')
  } catch (error) {
    // handle possible error
    self.postMessage('code ran with errors')
  }
})
```

main.js

```js
let worker = null

function run() {
  let code = '...'
  worker?.postMessage({ code  })
}

function stop() {
  if (worker == null) {
    worker = new Worker(pathToWorker)
    worker.addEventListener('message', event => {
      console.log(event.data)
    })
  } else {
    worker.terminate()
    worker = null
  }
}
```

[Web Workers Support (98%)](https://caniuse.com/webworkers)